# How can I use Middleware to define a section of a blade template?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have navigation bar that I'd like to show a link to the Admin Dashboard if the user logged in is an admin. If not, it should display nothing. I have something similar set up with guests e.g.

```
@if (Auth::guest())
        <li><a href="{{ url('/auth/login') }}">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('/auth/register') }}">Register</a></li>
    @else
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="{{ url('/profile') }}">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ url('/auth/logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
@endif
```

But how can I do this for a logged in user and an admin? I currently have

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a></li>
    @if (Auth::guest())

    @else
    <li><a href="{{ url('/admin') }}">Admin Dashboard</a></li>
    @endif
</ul>
```

I have middleware set up on the admin route like so

```
Route::get('admin', ['middleware' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@index']);
```

Which looks like

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->user()->role != 1)
    {
        return redirect('home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

And that's fine, I just don't know how to get it to define a section of a blade template.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like your user model has an attribute named `role`, so you can do something like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a></li>
    @if (Auth::user()->role != 1)
         {{-- I am not an admin user --}}
    @else
        {{-- I am an admin user --}}
    @endif
</ul>
```

If it is not your case, then you need add a new attribute to the user model. By that way you are able emulate the code above.

For a better code structure and order, I suggest to you make a fuction inside of user model like this:

```
public function isAdmin(){
    return (\Auth::check() && $this->role == 1);
}
```

or another one to check if it is a regular user:

```
/** An user who is authenticated but it is not an admin  */
public function isRegular(){
    return (\Auth::check() && $this->role != 1);
}
```

Then, in you application and views you can use them like:

```
@if (Auth::user()->isRegular())
     {{-- I am not an admin user --}}
@else
    {{-- I am an admin user --}}
@endif
```

Or

```
@if (Auth::user()->isAdmin())
     {{-- I am an admin user --}}
@else
    {{-- I am not an admin user --}}
@endif
```

Comment: This helped me solve the issue but I had to first do a if (Auth::check()) and then do my if (Auth::user()->role == 1) inside of that in order to get it to work.

Comment: ah that's very nice! Thank you! I've learned something new from this.